# force close TIME_WAIT connections by sending RST to dst and src?

Tags: mysql, networking, tcp, connection

The MySQL server had some few "Too many connections" warnings , and on the server there's a ton of  unknown TIME_WAIT connection on my system like:

```
# netstat -npat
tcp        0      0 10.36.88.132:19912      10.36.64.2:3306         TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 10.36.88.132:19424      10.36.64.2:3306         TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 10.36.88.132:26157      10.36.64.2:3306         TIME_WAIT   -
```

I need to close them without interrupting the server.

I can not afford `/etc/init.d/network restart` on this server or MySQL server.

So I figured to close them.

Is it possible to

1. get TCP Sequence ID from kernel
2. send `RST` to both src and dst

Any tool like that exists? Or is my idea bad?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you think there's some connection (haha) between the "[Too many connections](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/too-many-connections.html)" messages and the "TIME_WAIT" states. There isn't. The message indicates too many connections to the MySQL server process. The "TIME_WAIT" connections are already disconnected from the server.

Removing the connection in "TIME_WAIT" state won't solve your problem. They're just the breadcrumbs left behind by the connections that were causing the problem before they entered that state.